# How to check redo, undo spaces in ibd file?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, database-administration

How we can calculate the amount of space consumed by Redo / Undo logs in InnoDB data files for some particular table's ibd file in case of **innodb_file_per_table = 1**  AND  in ibdata file in case of **innodb_file_per_table=0**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[`innodb_undo_logs`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_undo_logs) , [`Innodb_available_undo_logs`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_available_undo_logs) , [Discussion](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-undo-tablespace.html) .  Note that there are more "spaces" in 5.7 than previous versions.

See also [unto tablespaces](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_undo_tablespaces) .

What are you fishing for?  Perhaps some new, and potentially useful, metric to monitor?  If so, let us in on your ideas.